# android - There is no default constructor for ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, oncreate, onpause, activity-lifecycle

I m making adapter to adapt my book collection to be visible in list view.

[image: kk]

Issue is solved if I add super(context, position):

```
    public BookAdapter(Context context, int position, List <Book> updatedBooksList) {
    super(context, position);
    this.context = context;
    this.booksList = updatedBooksList ;
}
```

However, I want to know why I need this argument (int position) and call superclass constructor?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Also, in the broader sense why do we always(?) need to call super.onCreate like here in every onCreate?

**Aren't we supposed to override all our activity lifecycle stages - 
onPause, onREsume, onStop, OnDestroy, yet we still have** to call super's in each of them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Issue is solved if I add super(context, position):

The second parameter is not a `position`. It is the ID of a layout resource, one that is used by default for the rows created by the `ArrayAdapter`. You can tell that by reading [the JavaDocs for the constructor that you are calling](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int%29).

> However, I want to know why I need this argument (int position) and call superclass constructor?

Because, as the IDE told you, there is no default constructor on `ArrayAdapter`. In Java, the "default constructor" is a zero-argument constructor. Every constructor in Java needs to chain to a superclass constructor. If the superclass has a zero-argument ("default") constructor, Java will chain to it automatically. If the superclass does not have a zero-argument constructor, you need to chain to a superclass constructor manually.

> Also, in the broader sense why do we always(?) need to call super.onCreate like here in every onCreate?

Because the developers who created `Activity` elected to make that a requirement.

> Aren't we supposed to override all our activity lifecycle stage

No. You override those that you need.

> yet we still have to call super's in each of them?

`Activity` wants to do its processing for those lifecycle methods, in addition to anything that you want to do. To enforce that, `Activity` demands that you chain to the superclass and throws a `SuperNotCalledException` if you do not.