# How to add a default contructor

Tags: java, android, constructor, default-constructor, android-lint

Hope I am not duplicating a question here, but all of the ones I found on stack exchange dont seem to fit my need.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public class custom_row_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
     custom_row_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> picId, String url, String fullUrl) {
         super(context, R.layout.activity_custom_row_adapter, picId);
}
     //Do stuff
```

Everything works fine in the app, now I try to generate a signed apk and I get a nice little error that I need a default constructor. So I decide that I will add one, now my code looks like this:

```
public class custom_row_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
    public custom_row_adapter() {
        super();
}
     custom_row_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> picId, String url, String fullUrl) {
         super(context, R.layout.activity_custom_row_adapter, picId);
}
//Do Stuff
```

Now I get a new error that it can't find a suitable constructor for `ArrayAdapter()`

So I get on google and find a couple posts and one tells me I can bypass that error by searching Instantiable in the Inspections tab and turning it to WARNING that it will fix it. Didn't work.

So how do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: for those of you saying I can just add `public custom_row_adpater(){}`
[image]

**EDIT 2**: Here are some more pictures, pay attention to the Error on bottom left:

What Works in debug:[image: What works in Debug]

Paul G's Answer:[image: Paul G's answer]

Defualt Constructor:[image: default constructor]

No Constructor:[image: No constructor]

Comment: If you need a default constructor just for the hell of it, you can have it as `public custom_row_adapter() { }`.

Comment: You are saying it builds fine, but the error only happens when you are generating a signed APK? Sounds fishy to me.

Comment: if I build>build apk it generates the debug apk with no errors, but when I try to generate a signed apk, the error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that for some reason the lint (wrongly) thinks that your adapter should be instantiatable. This apply to objects which may be instantiated by the system like activities, broadcast receivers, but not to adapters because they are always instantiated in the application's code. For example commonly used adapters like `ArrayAdapter` or `SimpleCursorAdapter` don't have a default constructor.

You can try to make Android Studio come to his senses, for example update the build tools, clean the workspace, delete the `build` directory... If it doesn't work you can add the requested (and useless) default contructor :

```
public custom_row_adapter() {
    super(null , 0);
    throw new RuntimeException("This is a workaround and should not be used");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What I was missing was using `null, 0` for the parameters of the super

Answer (score 1):

It's because [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#pubctors) doesn't define a no-argument constructor.  That's what the compiler looks for when you call super() with no parameters.  It needs, at a minimum, a Context and a resource (int) to initialize itself.

Comment: I'm Kind of new to Java, but understand what you are saying, but I don't know how to fix it. Could you give a solution in code form?

Comment: Just remove the call to super() in your no-arg constructor

Answer (score 1):

[ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) does not have a default i.e.zero-param constructor so you must override one of the ones it does have.  You can find more info here 
[android - There is no default constructor for ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333692/android-there-is-no-default-constructor-for-arrayadapter)

```
public class custom_row_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> { 
    public custom_row_adapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource); 
    }
```

Comment: Alright, thanks for the link. After reading it, I have come to the conclusion that I need to manually direct the ArrayAdapter to a superclass constructor manually. How would I achieve this? You said "override one of the ones it does have" What exactly do you mean by one of the ones? (Forgive me if it's obvious, I just can't seem to wrap my head around this whole thing)

Comment: POST EDIT: Thankyou for adding those lines of code. But after trying those lines of code, I still got the no default constructor error. I guess no arguments means absolutely zero.

Comment: @Pythogen You got rid of the zero-param constructor right? Also make sure you don't have any other constructors on your class that don't have a call to super on their first line

Comment: Yeah, 2 constructors, the default one you told me to use and my custom one that has the super on its first line.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are extending an **ArrayAdapter** you can instantiate you're object from here:

```
Custom_row_adapter customAdapter = new Custom_row_adapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, insertIntegerArray);
```

If you want some extra arguments in your **class** then create a custom **contructor**:

```
 public Custom_row_adapter(Context context, int resource, Integer[] array, arg extraArg) {
    super(context, resource, array);
    this.extraArg = extraArg;
 }
```

My advice is to rename your **class** to `Custom_row_adapter`. It's a good practice to start a class name with an **Upper Case** char.

Comment: From here do you mean my custom_row_adapter.java?
And where do I put my default constructor then? (Well not where but how do I do it without requiring arguments)

Could you post more information and maybe include the constructor from the first code example you gave?

Comment: @Pythogen no, I mean from your **context**, maybe an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) or a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Comment: @Pythogen since this class is extending an **ArrayAdapter** you don't need to place a constructor in it.

Comment: are you saying I should just copy and paste the custom_row_adapter to the file containing the array adapter? (Sorry if that was not at all what you were saying)

The file that calls the custom_row_adapter has this in it:

ListAdapter picAdapt = new custom_row_adapter(this, picList, url, fullUrl);

and then the custom_row_adapter class is in a new Java File, and if I delete the constructor totally, I get the message that there is no default constructor.

Comment: It would be nice to know the type of those arguments. Anyway, it's probably because there's not a constructor with that type/number of arguments in the **ArrayAdapter** class.

Comment: I'll post some more pictures and hope it will help you guys, thanks for putting up with me:P

Answer (score 0):

From JavaSE doc:

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

Giving an empty constructor body for a default constructor is the same as putting a super call i.e.

```
public custom_row_adapter() {
    super();
}
```

is the same as

```
public custom_row_adapter() {}
```

So it results in an error because there is no default constructor in the superclass, and explicit constructor invocation is required. In this case you could overload your constructor and call to that with **this(args)**, or call to some superclass constructor with **super(args)**.

Reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understand what you are asking.

#### Solution

Because `ArrayAdapter` does not have a default "no-arg" constructor, you must supply some arguments. I.e. instead of putting

```
public custom_row_adapter() {
    super();
}
```

You would instead need to specify (at least) two arguments. See the [Javadocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int)) for more information.

```
public custom_row_adapter() {
    super(context, resource);
}
```

What `context` and `resource` are needs to be determined by you. Since it's possible you might not need this constructor, they could possibly be `null` and some `int`, like `0` or `-1`.

#### Why

By default, when no constructor is provided for your class, Java automatically builds you one that does nothing (essentially). However, as soon as you create another constructor, the default one (`custom_row_adapter()`) "disappears". See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525548/default-constructors-and-inheritance-in-java) for additional info.

Also, by default, the first call of the no-arg constructor (`custom_row_adapter()`) is implicitly `super();` (see [Java SE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7)). Since `ArrayAdapter` doesn't have a default no-argument constructor, this is invalid, and you must supply arguments to it.